# Android: App not visible on 1920x1080 and 1280x720 resolution devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-resolution

I have developed a game and uploaded it on Play Store. But its not visible on 1920x1080 and 1280x720 resolution mobiles. The manifest file is as follows:

```
<!-- Mandatory Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<!-- Optional  Permissions (recommended)-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="false"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

The game is visible on Nexus 7(800x1280) Samsung Galaxy Tab2(600 x 1024), etc. I want devices with screen size less than 5 inches to be not able to see the game on Play Store hence have kept `smallScreens="false"` and `android:normalScreens="false"`. What changes do I need to make in Manifest file so that the game is visible on PlayStore for 1920x1080 and 1280x720 resolution devices and devices with screen size of 5inch and resolution density more than 200dpi?

Answer (score 1):

You need Extra Large Screen, Extra Density and Extra High Density.

Take a look at the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way that determines device just upon thier physical size.

For your question kindly refer ::

http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java#5899

Hope it helps!

Comment: But what about the resolutions? It must be visible to the 1920x1080 and 1280x720  phones. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Have U defined default layout for same ?

Answer (score 0):

May be using of compatible screens Tag will help you out.

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all  xlarge screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```