# My App is not compatible with Samsung Tab2

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

When I search my app from a Samsung tab 2 the application is not found, but when searching from other devices like the Galaxy s2 it is found. This app is compatible with some devices. I checked my manifest and permission but it is still incompatible -- Thanks in advance.

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" android:required="false"/>

<permission android:name="ads.mobisoft.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ads.mobisoft.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would comment instead of posting an "answer", but I am missing 4 reputation to do that -.-
So:

I think it is meant for really big screens like TV's, but did you try:

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

Maybe the tablet's screen is defined as extra large?

EDIT: Lock at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722458/android-app-not-visible-on-1920x1080-and-1280x720-resolution-devices?rq=1). That might help you a little further

Comment: You mean xlargeScreens="true", I guess, false is what the OP has set in his manifest already ;)

Comment: The dangers of copy&paste. Yeah I meant to write true, but forgot to change it. I have edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: hi @RedHairy i have other app in market without using <support screen> tag and its work on all tabs , in my opinion the problem because some of permission

Comment: Maybe all screens are supported if there is no <support screen> tag. I am not an expert in this topic, but i don't know, how the permission could have this effect as they all aren't required if i understand it correctly. I would try setting the xlargeScreens to true.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably:

```
android:xlargeScreens="false"
```

Change that to true